# only_full_group_by not letting me show a table as I want

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-5.7

I have a new VPS server with a MySQL server version 5.7.27. In this new VPS I have uploaded a database and some code I had from my previous server that had and older MySQL server version.

MySQL server version 5.7.27 has **only_full_group_by** enabled by default.
The problem arrives when in the new VPS server, I am trying to run a query that contains a GROUP BY statement that used to work in my old server but now in the new server I get the following message.

**1055: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'ihrwpmmy_loyal.i.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by**

I know there is the option of removing/disabling **only_full_group_by** but instead I would like to do thing properly an do the corrections to my query.

I have been reading and I have learned that adding **i.id** to the GROUP BY statement will show up the values in the table again, but I don’t really want to GROUP BY **i.id** instead  I would like to only GROUP BY **i.loadNumber** but I am been forced to GROUP BY **i.id** to remove the error.   I really need too GROUP BY **i.loadNumber** because I have duplicated load numbers I don't want to show on the table.

```
SELECT i.id AS ivoiceIDAOC,
        i.debtorId,
        i.loadNumber,
        i.amountUsd,
        i.sentDate,
        i.commissionStatus,
        i.paidDate,
        i.status,
        cp.amountUsd AS amountUsdCarriersPayments,
        i.amountUsd - SUM(cp.amountUsd) AS companyProfitUsd,
        ROUND((i.amountUsd - SUM(cp.amountUsd)) * 0.10, 2) AS salesRepProfitUsd,
        ROUND(((i.amountUsd - SUM(cp.amountUsd)) * 0.10) * 0.50, 2)  AS advanceOnCommissionUsd,
        l.id,
        l.clientName,
        l.repID
        FROM invoice i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN leads l ON i.debtorId = l.id
        INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON cp.loadNumber LIKE CONCAT('', i.loadNumber, '%')
        WHERE True
        ".$filter_AOC_date."
        ".$filter_AOC_salesRep."
        AND i.commissionStatus IS NULL
        GROUP BY
        i.id,
        i.loadNumber,
        cp.amountUsd
        ORDER BY i.id desc";
```

This is how the table looks like.

```
Load #|Customer Name| Paid Date |Revenue| Cost |Co Profit|SR Profit | AOC  |
------+-------------+-----------+-------+------+--------------------+------+
1570  | Customer 1  | 2019-09-19| $100  |  $50 |   $50   |   $5     | $2.5 |
1565  | Customer 2  | 2019-09-17| $102  |  $50 |   $52   |   $5.2   | $2.6 |
1565  | Customer 2  | 2019-09-16| $104  |  $50 |   $54   |   $5.4   | $2.7 |
1566  | Customer 3  | 2019-09-13| $106  |  $50 |   $56   |   $5.6   | $2.8 |
```

As you can see on the example table if I add **i.id** to my GROUP BY statement as I am forced, I obtain Load number **1565** twice.
I would like to see only different Load numbers.

```
Load #|Customer Name| Paid Date |Revenue| Cost |Co Profit|SR Profit | AOC  |
------+-------------+-----------+-------+------+--------------------+------+
1570  | Customer 1  | 2019-09-19| $100  |  $50 |   $50   |   $5     | $2.5 |
1565  | Customer 2  | 2019-09-17| $206  | $100 |   $106  |   $10.6  | $5.3 |
1566  | Customer 3  | 2019-09-13| $106  |  $50 |   $56   |   $5.6   | $2.8 |
```

Comment: You are being asked to use group by 'properly' (and compliantly) you should review mysql group by https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html particularly around the bits dealing with functional dependency and non determinancy. It might also be helpful if you reworded your question to state what you are trying to do and including sample data and expected output as tet in the question.

Comment: Your query is not clear  ..  try add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I have already updated the question with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in select some column not involbed in aggreagation function and not mentioned in group by  this is not allowed  by default for the most recent version of mysql

Furthermore you are using also the same column in select and in aggreation function this  is  rather strange you cannot use either one or the other, seems without sense

looking to you code  you coud refactor your query using a proper subquery

```
select loadNumber, SUM(amountUsd) sum_usd, SUM(amountCad) sum_cad
from  carriersPayments
group by loadNumber
```

example:

```
"SELECT i.id AS ivoiceIDAOC,
        i.debtorId,
        i.loadNumber,
        i.amountUsd,
        i.amountCad,
        i.sentDate,
        i.commissionStatus,
        i.paidDate,
        i.status,
        cp.amountUsd AS amountUsdCarriersPayments,
        cp.amountCad AS amountCadCarriersPayments,

        i.amountUsd - sum_usd AS companyProfitUsd,
        i.amountCad - sum_cad AS companyProfitCad,

        ROUND((i.amountUsd - sum_usd) * 0.10, 2) AS salesRepProfitUsd,
        ROUND((i.amountCad - sum_cad) * 0.10, 2) AS salesRepProfitCad,

        ROUND(((i.amountUsd - sum_usd) * 0.10) * 0.50, 2)  AS advanceOnCommissionUsd,
        ROUND(((i.amountCad - sum_cad) * 0.10) * 0.50, 2)  AS advanceOnCommissionCad,

        l.id,
        l.clientName,
        l.repID
        FROM invoice i
        INNER JOIN carriersPayments cp ON cp.loadNumber LIKE CONCAT('', i.loadNumber, '%')
        INNER JOIN  (
          select loadNumber, SUM(amountUsd) sum_usd, SUM(amountCad) sum_cad
          from  carriersPayments
          group by loadNumber 
          ) t ON t.loadNumber LIKE CONCAT('', i.loadNumber, '%')
        LEFT OUTER JOIN leads l ON i.debtorId = l.id
        WHERE True
        ".$filter_AOC_date."
        ".$filter_AOC_salesRep."
        AND i.commissionStatus IS NULL
        ORDER BY i.id desc";
```

and last you should not use php var in sql this is at risk for sqlinject .. for avoid this you should take a look a your db driver for prepared  statememnt and binding param.

Comment: Hi, I have been playing with your answer and trying to understand whats going on because I have never done a SELECT inside a INNER JOIN to replace a GROUP BY. I am super close to obtain the data as I want but I am missing something because I still see same Load Number on the table.  The code that I am using is exactly as you did on the example.  I wanted to mention important information.  There are some cases where 2 carriersPayments have same Load Number.   I have added examples on the top of how the table looks like and how I would like it to look.

Comment: without a proper data sample your comment is not clear to me  ..but if is useful you should think at the result of a subquery as  a table  .. so once you have obtained from the subquery  the (partial)  result you need you can use this select as temporary table  .. and use the key column for join ..  .. hope is useful  ..

Comment: if you have the same loadNumber  .. then the related  value are sum .. in one row only

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.   It was really useful, I was a little bit lost. Thanks again.